# Google Places - Search places without location parameter?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Im working on a android application. I want to search places using that application but in the url location parameter is a mandatory parameter. In my application user can freely search places. So in that case I don't know the location of the places that user searching. So how can I can search places without the location parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain clearly what you want. You are trying to say that you want to create an app that uses google maps to get places but google maps require specific address and in your app a user can enter any place. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, google places api require a specific location to search nearby places. But is there a way to search without giving a location? I hope it is clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Text Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests).  Only a `query` is required.